# Symlinking with (i.e.) find | sed | xargs without xargs: argument line too long

Tags: linux, bash, find, sed, xargs

I got stuck at symlinking using find, xargs and sed.

### Given folder structure:

```
/abc
 /def
 /*/def

/builds
```

on my local machine the following statement works.

```
find ./abc \
      -type d \
      -name def \
      -prune \
      -maxdepth 3 \
      -print0 | \
        parallel -0 /bin/bash \
          -c 'echo "/builds/{}" > >(sed -e "s/\.\/abc\///") | \
            parallel -I % ln -s % {}'
```

... successfully symlinking all `/def` directories found in `/abc` to `/builds/def` and `/builds/*/def`.

**However** my pipeline throws `xargs: argument line too long`.

At first I had thought I can do something like:

```
ln -s <(parameter1) <(parameter2)
```

... but from what it looks like, `ln` does not accept file inputs.

After some research, `GNU Parallel` seems to be the better tool for the job, but it won't let me do the following.

`parallel -0 /bin/bash -c 'echo "/builds/{}" > >(sed -e "s/\/abc\///") | parallel -I % ln -s % {}'`

What would be the simplest and most logical solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up doing this:

```
find ./abc \
  -type d \
  -name def \
  -prune \
  -maxdepth 3 | parallel -q /bin/bash -c 'var=$(echo "/builds/{}" > >(sed -e "s/\.\/abc\///"));ln -s {} $var'
```

Comment: woops, still had an echo in there instead for test-purposes. fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Shorter:

```
find ./abc \
  -type d \
  -name def \
  -prune \
  -maxdepth 3 | parallel ln -s {} '{= s:^./abc:/builds: =}'
```